# Catching waitForSelector Errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, ui-automation, puppeteer

I use a module called [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).

I tried waiting for a selector on my page that may not appear. Out of the two approaches I took, only the try-catch method worked.

**try-catch block - working**

```
try {
    await page.waitForSelector('.element');
    //element appeared
} catch (error) {
    //element did not appear
}
```

**promise chaining - not working**

```
await page.waitForSelector('.element')
    .catch((error) => { 
        //element did not appear
    })
    .then(() => {
        //element appeared
    });
```

It seems that `waitForSelector` does return a Promise as indicated in the API, but I can't figure why the latter approach didn't work. It threw the error anyway.

Have anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should restructure your Promise Chaining example to use the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method before the [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method.

Consider the following example using [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
// Correct Method
await page.waitForSelector('#example').then(() => {
  console.log('SUCCESS');
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('FAIL');
});
```

If the element does not exist, then `FAIL` will be logged to the console. Otherwise, if the element does exist, the output will be `SUCCESS`.

On the other hand, take a look at the example below in which [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) are reversed:

```
// Incorrect Method
await page.waitForSelector('#example').catch(e => {
  console.log('FAIL');
}).then(() => {
  console.log('SUCCESS - not necessarily');
});
```

If the element does not exist, then `FAIL` will be logged to the console, but regardless of whether the element exists or not, `SUCCESS` will also be written to the console. This is because logging `SUCCESS` is the next immediate step in the chain after attempting to catch an error.

Using [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) before [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) will allow you to print one of two messages and achieve your desired result.